# Are moral dilemmas within the scope of philosophy stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, questions

Are moral dilemmas within the scope of philosophy stackexchange?

[Which philosophers would allow the rape of their lover, in order to lower the possibility of some global political evil?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94602/which-philosophers-would-allow-the-rape-of-their-lover-in-order-to-lower-the-po)

If it's because it seems too artificial, then will it be reopened when I add some context (e.g. a mad scientist that hates you and has lusted after your lover has kidnapped her and is threatening to share some military secret with Nazi Germany, if you do not allow her rape).

It clearly is a "moral dilemma", and I've seen more bizarre ones (kidnapping, threatening to give someone an STD, etc.)

Comment: It is kind of like coming up with endless variants of the Trolley Problem, it doesn't really lead anywhere. You can only investigate your blind spot for so long. Plenty of James Bond movies out there to consider... Mission Impossible...

Comment: So you mean I should use an example from Mission Impossible? @ScottRowe the trolley problem does not include lots of salient details the scenario did include

Comment: Well, my point was that humans can cook up hideous and disturbing scenarios endlessly. How many books and tv and movies are there about, murder mysteries for example? How many more are added every day? How wildly popular are they? Any one specific example you could ask about is going to be lost in the noise, or just plain uninteresting, at least to me. I have a very low tolerance for violent imagery, and have since watching the Vietnam War at dinner every night when I was a child. But, that probably doesn't interest you.

Comment: What do you mean? I am reading your comments and am interested in what you have to say @ScottRowe So I got -4 votes cos you didn't like my imagination. That makes sense

Comment: I remember the poll tax riots and thatcherism, the economic misery @ScottRowe probably a similar odd formative memory (I was 8). I may not be a complete pacifist, but...

Comment: I didn't see the original question and apparently I can't see it now. I recall passing it by without a look because it doesn't seem useful or constructive on the face of it. I'm not in the police business, so I don't usually look in to such things. Not sure if anyone else here agrees with me. Were you given a reason as to why it was closed?

Comment: It was closed as lacking "context" and so I added the above flesh / imaginative scenario, but it then attracted another -2 votes and was rejected for re-opening, so who cares @ScottRowe it was a very unpopular question. As someone suggested, it was probably too emotive for anyone else to find useful